# Google Cloud build always deploys my cloud-function with previous commit

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I have a problem with my automated cloud function deployment

I have a cloud function stored in a Google Cloud repository

Git code includes a cloudbuild.yaml file with this content :

```yaml
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["functions", "deploy", "myfunction", "--region=europe-west1"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

I only have a branch Master.

When i push my commit, cloudbuild triggers and deploys the cloud function

The problem is that it always deploys the previous commit, not the last

For example :
2:23 : I push my source code to Google Source repository

Here is the result :

[image: Commit from local source]

At 2:23:33, cloudbuild triggers and deploys successfully the cloud function

[image]

Here is the log of Cloudbuild :

```sh
starting build "e3a0e735-50fc-4315-bafd-03128156d69f"

FETCHSOURCE
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/myproject/r/myrepo
 * branch            1b67729b8498c35fc19a45b14b8d674635300594 -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at 1b67729 PrayingforCommit
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...
...............................................done.
availableMemoryMb: 256
entryPoint: process_gcs
eventTrigger:
  eventType: google.storage.object.finalize
  failurePolicy: {}
  resource: projects/_/buckets/mybucket
  service: storage.googleapis.com
ingressSettings: ALLOW_ALL
labels:
  deployment-tool: cli-gcloud
name: projects/myproject/locations/europe-west1/functions/myfunction
runtime: python37
serviceAccountEmail: myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
sourceRepository:
  deployedUrl: https://source.developers.google.com/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo/revisions/2ed14c3225e7fcc089f2bc6a0ae29c7564ec12b9/paths/
  url: https://source.developers.google.com/projects/myproject/repos/myrepo/moveable-aliases/master/paths/
status: ACTIVE
timeout: 60s
updateTime: '2020-04-15T00:24:55.184Z'
versionId: '2'
PUSH
DONE
```

As you can see, the commit that triggers is the 1b67729, but the DeployedUrl line says 2ed14c3 which is the previous commit

Operation ended at 2:24:55, i see the same time in my cloud function source tab

[image]

If i just click the edit button, then deploy button, to manually force the cloud function rebuild, it deploys the correct commit (1b67729)

[image]

Here are the parameters of the cloud-function :

[image]

Where is my mistake with cloudbuild, and how to always deploy the last commit ???

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you facing this issue recently? Could you please share when you first start encountering this issue? Before is it working correctly?

Comment: Hi Nibrass, thanks for your interest

I have several projects using cloudbuild
Regarding to the build history, the last correct deployment was February, 16th

`From ...
 * branch            35ac17fa2360c0c409f83447842054b33763f49c -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at 35ac17f typo
BUILD
[...]
deployedUrl: .../revisions/35ac17fa2360c0c409f83447842054b33763f49c/paths/
[...]
PUSH
DONE`

Comment: Found a workaround
- Drop both trigger and repository
- Modify the cloudbuild (setting the new repository for cloudfunction with --source parameter)
- Recreate the trigger
- Push my local git
The question remains open, i have no idea of why cloudbuild had this strange behavior with the old repository

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Were you able to create a new repository with the old cloudbuild file and deploy. Does it also deploy the last commit? Or just it's happening with your old repository?

Comment: I have the same issue, no work-around found yet. I enlisted a 2nd pair of eyes for hours, and we found nothing. I don't know how to trace the cause. In my case though, I have the issue with 2 repos that I deploy cloud functions from, whereas another 4 (similar) repos that I deploy cloud functions from in the same way are just fine. All done from Terraform.

Answer (score 3):

## Cloud Functions does not check for updates to source repos when the --source flag is omitted

The function was previously deployed directly from a source repository and you are not passing a `--source` flag to gcloud.  Under these circumstances gcloud ignores the code in the local directory.

The easiest fix is to explicitly specify the source in your cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["functions", "deploy", "myfunction", "--region=europe-west1", "--source=."]
timeout: "1600s"
```

(You would not hit this if the function had never been configured to fetch its source directly from the repository.)

### Explanation

#### 1. The Cloud Function has previously been deployed from a source repository

When configuring a Cloud Function, there is an option to fetch source code from a Cloud Source Repository.  You are prompted with this as an option when creating a function through the console, but could also have used gcloud:

```
gcloud functions deploy NAME \
    --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/PROJECT_ID/repos/REPOSITORY_ID/moveable-aliases/master/paths/SOURCE \
    [... other gcloud options ...]
```

This is the 'sourceRepository' setting that you can see in the build output.

However, as you can see in the console (`resolved to 1b67729b`) Cloud Functions is not *updating* its code from there.

#### 2. Omitting the --source flag to gcloud in these circumstances leads to potentially confusing behaviour

When you leave out the `--source` flag to gcloud, if the function was previously deployed directly from a repository, specific behaviour applies. From the documentation for [gcloud functions deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy):

> If you do not specify the --source flag:
>
> - The current directory will be used for new function deployments.
> - If the function was previously deployed using a local filesystem path, then the function's source code will be updated using the
>   current directory.
> - If the function was previously deployed using a Google Cloud Storage location or a source repository, then the function's source
>   code will not be updated.

You are hitting the third option.

### Conclusion: Avoid linking Cloud Functions directly to the source repository when deploying through Cloud Build

Cloud Build is configured to run gcloud in a directory containing a copy of your source code.  You can therefore deploy directly from the local filesystem - this packages up the function in a zip file, uploads it to Cloud Storage, and tells Cloud Functions to fetch it.

If you tell Cloud Functions to fetch its code from a repository, then a second checkout of the repo is made and a zip file created from there, which will be slightly slower (and potentially prone to a race condition if the branch has updated in the background).

Answer (score 0):

The repository wasn't synced in my case - in the build log it kept showing the HEAD was from a build weeks ago

went to: https://source.cloud.google.com/ re-synced and my branches updated